# why it still need load Python when use cx_freeze distutils setup script in macox

Tags: macos, cx-freeze, distutils

when execute the test1 file, follow error happen:

```
 dyld: Library not loaded:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python
    Referenced from: xx/xx/xx/xx/build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/test1
    Reason: image not found
    [1]    47834 abort      retrain
```

my setup.py as follow:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

packages = ["numpy", "tensorflow"]

excludes = ["yaml", "xmlrpc", "xml", "urllib", "pydoc_data", "psutil", "multiprocessing",
            "h5py", "lib2to3", "http", "html", "email", "curses", "cpuinfo", "concurrent",
            "tensorflow.contrib.ios_examples", "tensorflow.examples"]
setup(
    name='test1',
    version="0.1",
    description="",
    options={"build_exe": {"packages":  packages, "excludes": excludes}},
    executables=[Executable("test1.py")])
```

execute otool -L test1, the result as follow:

```
xx/xx/xx/xx/build/exe.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/test1:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/Python (compatibility version 3.5.0, current version 3.5.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1349.90.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I sloved this problem by change command "python setup.py build" to "python setup.py bdist_dmg". Some error happend, such as xxx is not a Mach-O file, but it doesn't matter. The same file you need were generated in Mac folder inside the xxx.app folder as the way generate by command "python setup.py build".